# RANKX Filters - Fantasy Football Database

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

Farily new with DAX and struggling with filtered RANKX. I have a StatsDB table and a playerkey table for a fantasy football database I'm working on.

Each row of the data table is a game log for a player:

> **StatsDB**:
>
> - **PlayerID (relation)**
> - Year
> - **Name**
> - **Position**
> - Team
> - Week
> - Pass Attempts
> - Pass Completions
> - etc. - Other relevant offense statistics.
>
> **PlayerKey**
>
> - **PlayerID (relation)**
> - Player Name
> - Current Position

I created measures that calculate fantasy points based on stats.

> Example Measures:
>
> - **FPTS Rush Yds:**=CALCULATE(sum([Rush Yards])*.1)
> - **FPTS Total:**=[FPTS Fumb Lost]+[FPTS Rush Yds]+[FPTS Pass TDs]+ etc.

I have a points rank that seems to work for the context of the pivot / slicers.

```
FPTS Rank =
IF (
    NOT (
        ISBLANK ( [FPTS Total] )
    ),
    RANKX (
        FILTER (
            ALL ( PlayerKey ),
            NOT (
                ISBLANK ( [FPTS] > [Total] )
            )
        ),
        [FPTS Total]
    ),
    BLANK ()
)
```

However, my goal is to have a "fantasy points positional rank" measure. **Where did a player rank in fantasy points scored at his position over any given period of time?**

Any ideas how to go about this? Would be much appreciated! I can do this manually but am trying to work positional ranks into the data model and am stuck.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected outcome?

Comment: I have corrected spellings in your measure. Check if it works now.